# iPhone Use POST In NSMutableURLRequest to Add Fields to JSON

Tags: ios, post, nsmutableurlrequest, bigcommerce

I am trying to use the BigCommerce API to be able to add a customer using my iPhone app.  Here is what I have.

```
-(IBAction)gettingcustomers {

    NSString *post = @"first_name=AA&last_name=AA&email=jimbob3332002%40yahoo.com";


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myserver/customers.json"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:10];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
    [connection release];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"myusername"
                                                                    password:@"myapikey"
                                                                 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        NSLog(@"credential created");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE%@", response);
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        //If you need the response, you can use it here


        NSLog(@"%@", [httpResponse allHeaderFields]);
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"YAY" message:@"You exist" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"DIDFINISHLOADING");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didfailwitherror");
}
```

Using this, I get a response that the connection was successful and received data, but nothing gets posted.  The API documentation for POST customers.json says that all fields required are first_name last_name and email.

Comment: What do you mean "connection was successful and received data"? I don't see that in code.

Comment: @MarcusAdams in the connectionDidReceiveResponse method I have `if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        NSLog(@"%@", [httpResponse allHeaderFields]);
    }` and it shows in the log `{
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Wed, 03 Jul 2013 17:28:27 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-BC-ApiLimit-Remaining" = 19982;
    "X-BC-Store-Version" = "7.5.30";
    "X-Powered-By" = PleskLin;
}`

Comment: You should again take a look in the docs. It seems, you need to transfer data in JSON or XML using UTF-8. (Your POST data is not JSON)

Comment: Your authentication code is also not correct. First, for each challenge you need to determine the _authentication method_ which is in the protection space. Then, for each authentication method provide the corresponding credentials. If you need further help, this deserves a dedicated question. There are already answers to this problem on SO, too.

Comment: Note: for server trust evaluation: if BigCommerce's certificate is signed by a well known Certificate Authority, then the default mechanism provided by NSURLConnection will work automatically.